# MySQL query WHERE IN + ORDER BY, which EXPLAIN is better and how to avoid filesort?

Tags: mysql, index, optimization, query-performance

This is my table definition, without any special index for now:

```
CREATE TABLE `filter` (
  `field_name` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `category_id` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `position` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `options` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT '(DC2Type:json_array)',
  PRIMARY KEY (`field_name`,`category_id`),
  KEY `IDX_702C956612469DE2` (`category_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_702C956612469DE2` 
      FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Sample data:

```
+------------+-----------------------+-------------+----------+
| field_name |        options        | category_id | position |
+------------+-----------------------+-------------+----------+
| color      | {"label": "Color"}    |        1895 |        1 |
| material   | {"label": "Material"} |        1895 |        2 |
| color      | {"label": "Color"}    |        1896 |        1 |
| color      | {"label": "Color"}    |        1897 |        1 |
+------------+-----------------------+-------------+----------+
```

Most of the time I do a query with `WHERE IN` and `ORDER BY position` and selecting only `field_name` and `options`:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT 
  field_name
  options
FROM 
  filter
WHERE 
  category_id IN ('1895', '1896', '1897') 
ORDER BY 
  position ASC
```

This gives me **Using index condition; Using filesort**, quite bad uh?

```
{
   "query_block":{
      "select_id":1,
      "ordering_operation":{
         "using_filesort":true,
         "table":{
            "table_name":"filter",
            "access_type":"range",
            "possible_keys":[
               "IDX_702C956612469DE2"
            ],
            "key":"IDX_702C956612469DE2",
            "used_key_parts":[
               "category_id"
            ],
            "key_length":"98",
            "rows":5,
            "filtered":100,
            "index_condition":"(`filter`.`category_id` in ('1895','1896','1897'))"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

With an index on `category_id, position` **Using where; Using index; Using filesort**:

```
{
   "query_block":{
      "select_id":1,
      "ordering_operation":{
         "using_filesort":true,
         "table":{
            "table_name":"filter",
            "access_type":"range",
            "possible_keys":[
               "IDX_702C956612469DE2",
               "IDX_CATEGORY_POSITION"
            ],
            "key":"IDX_CATEGORY_POSITION",
            "used_key_parts":[
               "category_id"
            ],
            "key_length":"98",
            "rows":5,
            "filtered":100,
            "using_index":true,
            "attached_condition":"(`filter`.`category_id` in ('1895','1896','1897'))"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

So which explain is better? I would say the first because of **using index condition** (there is no "where" part). Is there any way to avoid the filesort?

Comment: One question - how many rows do you expect to get in average? In your plans there are 5 rows expected - filesort on 5 rows would be trivial if only longtext could be sorted in memory, but it has to go to disk according to [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/internal-temporary-tables.html). You could extract longtext to a different table to get over this, but hard to say if it is viable. Your order is actually sort of undefined as multiple categories can have a field with the same position - what about sorting by (category_id,position) ? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aabaa/7 - solves it

Comment: Just noticed that your plans are probably a bit skewed, because your query selects only one field, there shoud be a comma after `field_name` - as it is `options` is an alias for `field_name` - thats why you get `Using index`in the second plan.

Comment: @jkavalik I expect at least ~1000 rows. About longtext, I could trim it down to a limited varchar it this would solve the "problem". For sorting by category_id,position your are right: it should be by both fields, my mistake, but I still get using where, using index (not like your fiddle).

Comment: "Using index" means it is doing index-only scan - so you are probably not selecting options - check my second comment about a comma and the fiddle - and what does your query return without explain (because "using index" is not possible for text/blob columns at all). The index on (category_id, position) seems perfect for where in by first and order by both.

Comment: When I started writing it, it did not seem yet like a viable solution, just some notes and data gathering. Will make it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the structure of multicolumn B-tree index it is not viable to do a sort on `position` when using IN on `category_id`. But as the test data suggest the `position` is not "global" but seems to have a meaning only for given `category_id`. So as I suggested in comments, it is instead possible to `ORDER BY (category_id, position)` - that can use two-column index on those columns to get it without filesort. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aabaa/7

Because of the longtext column it is not possible to turn this into an index-only scan (text columns can be only indexed on prefix, not on entire value, as index key length is limited).

Using varchar fields as primary key has some drawbacks, but it is not "wrong" by itself so just a little suggestion - would it make sense in your desing to use some integer ids instead?